# Solving N+1 hibernate problem on a nested one to many relational tables

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, spring-data-jpa, fetch

I have an Organization table, Department Table and Employee table.
One Organization has many Departments and one Department has many Employees.
On executing `findByOrganizationId`(PK of Organization), I see the Employee table also getting queried n number of times where n is number of Department for an organization.

How do I avoid getting the Employee data while doing the same?
I see a N+1 issue here. But not sure how to avoid it in nested one to many mapping.

Fetch type is set to LAZY.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private List<Employee> employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` overrules `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` as it becomes `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. Try to remove fetch annotation and it will not query N+1 relationship.

Comment: Hi, I tried removing @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
it gave the below error.
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sales.Employee, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: please provide Organization model code and the call of findByOrganizationId method.